# Generate Localizable.strings file based on occurrences of NSLocalizedString in codebase Swift

Tags: swift

I have a codebase were I've used `NSLocalizedString` everywhere. I now want some kind of script or tool that finds all these `NSLocalizedString` and formats a `Localizable.strings` file. Does this exist? I'd hate to have to do this manually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## 1

You can use `genstrings` as @Extra Savoir-Faire noted.

1. Create a file names `en.lproj` in the root directory of your project.
2. `cd` into the project from the terminal.
3. Run this command `find ./ -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o en.lproj`

This should export all files ending with swift that have a `NSLocalizedString`.

Also you can have the `en.lproj` anywhere as long as you run this command in the it's parent directory (you can see it when run the `ls` command

## 2

You can also export the file directly from Xcode.. the .strings file.

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Select `Product`
3. Select `Export Localizations`
4. Select the desired package
5. Select location and export.

When you go to the folder you exported. You will find the `Localizable.strings` in

`en.xcloc` -> `Source Contents` -> `YourProjectName`-> `en.lproj`

You can use the `Localizable.strings` from there.

Comment: Do you have a good way to update the `Localizable.strings` as more are added?

Comment: I have not got into that but, I think [this](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) tool should help. I think every time you build it takes a look at the `NSLocalizedString`s in the project and adds/removes accordingly.

Comment: 1 - doesn't work. It seems to be obsolete. 2 - doesn't work because of `Unable to build project for localization string extraction. Please see the build logs for failure description.`

Answer (score 0):

I've used this app before to do what you’re asking about: http://linguanapp.com.

Comment: 1)it doesn't work; 2)it is paid and "save and export" is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Per Apple's documentation:

> Although you can create strings files manually, it is rarely necessary
> to do so. If you write your code using the appropriate string-loading
> macros, you can use the genstrings command-line tool to extract those
> strings and create strings files for you.